# Error in Google Cloud Function to read XML data from URL and load into a Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: python, xml, url, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

For a use case that I am working on, I would like to create a Cloud Function that takes a URL to an XML file as parameter, and loads this file into an already created Cloud Storage Bucket, let's call the bucket "xml-data". I have constructed a function that looks as following:

```
import requests
from google.cloud import storage


def load_xml_to_gcs(request):
    bucket_name = "xml-data"
    xml_file_url = {The URL to the XML data}

    # Fetch the XML file from the URL
    response = requests.get(xml_file_url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return f"Failed to fetch XML file from {xml_file_url}"

    # Create a Cloud Storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Create a new blob in the specified bucket
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob("xml-feed-data.xml")

    # Set the content type of the blob to XML
    blob.content_type = "application/xml"

    # Upload the XML content to the blob
    blob.upload_from_string(response.text)

    return "XML file successfully loaded to Cloud Storage"


# Testing the function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_xml_to_gcs(None)
```

When I test this function in the Cloud Functions interface providing the actual URL to the XML file, I am faced with an "500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application" error.

Could anyone help me resolve what this error depends on or suggest an alternative way to write this function? Thanks!

Kind regards,
Bertan

Comment: Why do you call this function with None?